# NestJS - Inject dependency after service startup

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, nestjs

I want to inject data that is only available at runtime,
is this possible with `NestJS` ?

```
  app.inject({ name, value })
```

```js
export const start = async (config: Config) => {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    ApplicationModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({ ignoreTrailingSlash: true }),
  );


  // how can I 
  
  // app.inject({ name, value }) ?

  return app.listen(config.port, '0.0.0.0');
};
```

Comment: What's the use case here?

Comment: I have data which is only available at runtime, 
I want to inject it as a config so it's available in controllers.

Comment: I still don't think I understand. If it's available at runtime, couldn't you inject the place it's available from to the provider/controller where it will be used?